# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS works only with a string, not with a list as expected

Tags: django, django-csrf, netbox

## Context

I am running a Netbox instance, which uses Django. Inside of its parameters, I have to set `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` to the origins I trust for Netbox to work properly.

The Netbox instance I use runs inside a Docker container ([netbox-docker](https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox-docker)).

## Issue

I have found out that if I write these as a list, like expected in the documentation ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins)), I get a 403 error with the following description: `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.` Activating debug mode also tells me this: `Origin checking failed - https://myurl does not match any trusted origins.`, which I do not understand because my variable looks like this: `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=['https://172.23.0.5', 'https://myurl']`.

## Temporary workaround

If I set the variable as a simple string, I do not get any error: `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="https://myurl"` works flawlessly for `myurl` (of course, it still blocks all the other URLs).

## Issue (still)

That worked for some time, but now I have to add a second domain name referencing my Netbox instance, so I would need to add `"https://myurl2"` to the trusted origins list. Since having a list does not work here, I do not really know how to proceed.

## What I have tried

I have tried to change the way I assign its value to the variable:

- `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="https://myurl","https://myurl2"`
- `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS="https://myurl" "https://myurl2"`

Those syntaxes just gave me syntax errors (for example, `unexpected character "\"" in variable name`).

## TL;DR

My Netbox (running with Django) only accepts the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` variable as a string for it to work, while it is supposed to take a list according to its documentation. I need to set more than one trusted origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was a problem within the netbox-docker implementation. The env file where this parameter was defined actually needed the following format for the variable:
`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=https://myurl https://myurl2` (same I did try but without quotes).